# Create a directory in /var/lib

Tags: python, permissions, mkdir, directory-permissions

I'm using the following code to create a directory (if it doesn't exist) and a file inside that directory:

```
import os

mystr = 'hello world!'
mypath = '/salam/me/'

if not os.path.exists(mypath):
    oldmask = os.umask(000)
    os.makedirs(mypath, 0755)
    os.umask(oldmask)

text_file = open(mypath + "myfile", "w")
text_file.write("%s" % mystr)
text_file.close()
```

But I get `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` from the console. I followed answers to other similar questions and they suggested unmasking and using `0755`/`0o755`/`0777`/`0o777`

But they don't seem to work in this case. What am I doing wrong?

Follow up question: I want to do this job in `/var/lib/`. Is it going to be different? (in terms of setting up the permission)

**NOTE** This is Python version 2.7

Comment: If you put permission 777 on /salam/me/ problem is solved?

Comment: how could it be?

Comment: the dir doesn't exist. How should I put 777 on it?

Comment: The question title and the second question in the body are very different: `os.makedirs('/salam/me',...)` will try to create it under `/` which is owned by root, but typically your Python script will be running under some user. As to asking *"I want to do this job in /var/lib/, Is it going to be different?"*, that's a question about Unix permissions, not about Python (if you typed `mkdir ...` from command-line, while under that user account, it would also fail). Also, you imply but never say your OS is Linux; it helps to say which version is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run the script as root because the parent folder `/var/lib` is owned by root. The umask commands aren't needed.

Besides that, I would rewrite the code like this to avoid a race condition:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

mystr = 'hello world!'
mypath = '/salam/me/'

try:
    os.makedirs(mypath, 0755)
except FileExistsError:
    print('folder exists')

text_file = open(mypath + "myfile", "w")
text_file.write("%s" % mystr)
text_file.close()
```

Then run the script as root:

```
sudo python3 my_script.py
```

---

PS: If you are bound to Python 2, you need to replace `FileExistsError` by `OSError` in the above solution. But you have to additionally check `errno`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import errno
import os

mystr = 'hello world!'
mypath = '/salam/me/'

try:
    os.makedirs(mypath, 0755)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
        print('folder exists')
    else:
        raise

text_file = open(mypath + "myfile", "w")
text_file.write("%s" % mystr)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: did you assume a specific version of python? because I'm using 2.7 and it says `FileExistsError` doesn't exist

Comment: I was assuming python3. With python2 you are bound to `OSError` (which is more generic and not exactly saying that the folders exists. could be some other error as well). Use python3 if possible

Comment: is there any other exception more specific than `OSError` to catch ?

Comment: I've updated my answer and showed a solution which specifically handles `EEXIST`. A few lines more code but as good as the python3 solution